# How to install and upgrade rpm packages in a custom folder?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to use yum_package to install rpm files stored in to the base directory under the root/gpfs_driver path

```
%w("gpfs.*.*.rpm").each do |pkg|
    package "#{pkg}" do

            source "/root/gpfs_drive/base/"

            action :install

    end
end
```

Error:

```
    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /root/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/preq/recipes/test.rb:2:in `block in from_file'

    yum_package(""gpfs.*.*.rpm"") do
      package_name "\"gpfs.*.*.rpm\""
      action [:install]
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      declared_type :package
      cookbook_name "preq"
      recipe_name "test"
      source "/root/gpfs_drive/base/"
      flush_cache {:before=>false, :after=>false}
    end

    System Info:
    ------------
    chef_version=12.21.3
    platform=redhat
    platform_version=7.2
    ruby=ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
    program_name=chef-client worker: ppid=23043;start=17:09:14;
    executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client

[2018-04-13T17:09:19+10:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception

Running handlers: 
[2018-04-13T17:09:19+10:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers Running handlers complete 
[2018-04-13T17:09:19+10:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 04 seconds 
[2018-04-13T17:09:19+10:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /root/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out 
[2018-04-13T17:09:19+10:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report 
[2018-04-13T17:09:19+10:00] ERROR: yum_package["gpfs.*.*.rpm"] (preq::test line 2) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of rpm -qp --queryformat '%{NAME} %{VERSION}-%{RELEASE} %{ARCH} ' /root/gpfs_drive/base/ ---- STDOUT: STDERR: error: open of /root/gpfs_drive/base/ failed: No such file or directory
---- End output of rpm -qp --queryformat '%{NAME} %{VERSION}-%{RELEASE} %{ARCH} ' /root/gpfs_drive/base/ ---- Ran rpm
-qp --queryformat '%{NAME} %{VERSION}-%{RELEASE} %{ARCH} ' /root/gpfs_drive/base/ returned 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Chef does not work in that way.

First of all, `%w("gpfs.*.*.rpm")` will not list all the packages in the directory. It is just an alias for array. You should rather do `Dir.glob("/root/gpfs_drive/base/gpfs.*.*.rpm")`.

Then you have to put full path in the `source`.

From the top of my head:

```
Dir.glob("/root/gpfs_drive/base/gpfs*.rpm").each do |pkg|
  rpm_package pkg do
    source pkg
    action :install
  end
end
```

`Dir.glob` should return all the packages with full path, you can iterate over the list/array.

Comment: You might need to `basename` things for the package name to be correct, I don't remember if we fix that for you on local installs.

Comment: @coderanger do you want me to use execute or bash to perform this action execute 'prereq' do
  user 'root'
    command "yum -y install /root/gpfs_driver/base/* \
    && yum -y update gpfs_driver/update/* \
    && yum install kernel-devel-`uname -r` cpp gcc gcc-c++ \
   &&  /usr/lpp/mmfs/bin/mmbuildgpl \
    && cp mmglobfuncs.Linux /usr/lpp/mmfs/bin/"

Comment: The most correct solution depends on a lot of specifics of your use case, the main issue with expanding a glob as shown is that it runs the glob at compile time. If that's fine, then you should use this example.

Comment: @Szymon Szypulski, I did try rpm_package, I get the same error